# How to Reverse a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I want to reverse the stars from (smallest to biggest) to (Biggest to smallest)

```
  function seethestars1() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "*";
            }
            document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "\n";
        }
    }

 <textarea id="emptytext2" name="S2">

 <input id="emptytext3" type="button" value="Click for the stars" onclick ="seethestars1()" />
```

Comment: `var i = 10; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: `{ )++i ;01 =< i ;0 = i rav( rof` \s

Comment: Do your Assignments yourself bro. :) Grow to be the helper!

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: @user2751035 : what have you tried ??

Comment: Please, get the element by id ONCE and store that in a variable, and use that variable to access the value. Every call to getElementById is expensive and should be minimized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
```

But I'm not sure why are you doing so because you are not using this variable inside your loop so I think it doesn't make any difference to the output as you loop going to run 10 times either way.

If I could guess then I think you want to print the stars in reverse order of quantity. That means you want to have maximum stars in first row then -1 in second and so on.. If so then you need to reverse the order of *inner loop* only like this

```
 function seethestars1() {
    var stars = document.getElementById("emptytext2");
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 10; j > i; j--) {
            stars.value += "*";
        }                            
      stars.value += "\n";
    }
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WUVuZ/1/)

Comment: Don't call getElementById in every loop. It is quite expensive. [Get the element once and use that for all manipulation](http://jsfiddle.net/some/558Kh/).

Comment: good point @some agreed and updated the post. Thanks :)

Comment: You could change either the outer or inner loop. My opinion is that it is clearer to change the outer loop `(i = 10; i > 0; --i)` and keep the inner loop as `(j = 0; j < i; ++j)`

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following code for seethestarts1 method.

```
function seethestars1() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (var j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "*";
            }
            document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function seethestars2() {
        for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "*";
            }
            document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "\n";
        }
    }
```

what is happening here is simple; instead of starting from 1 star, it is starting from 10 stars in the `outer loop` with counter `i`.
The `inner loop` is just the same as before.

Comment: This is in my opinion the most clear way to do it. If you change it so that you don't call getElementById in every loop (it is quite an expensive call) I will give you an upvote. http://jsfiddle.net/some/558Kh/

Answer (score 0):

Put one for loop in reverse order. Try following:

```
function seethestars1() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (var j = 10; j > i; j--) {
                document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "*";
            }
            document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "\n";
        }
}
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/s5ztu/

Comment: Don't call getElementById in every loop. It is quite expensive. Get the element once and use that for all manipulation. And when you fiddle, put the javascript in the javascript section: http://jsfiddle.net/some/558Kh/